# Is it possible to treat hyphens and spaces the same in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

So I'm working on a search function for a social networking site, and it searches user posts. Some users like to put hyphens instead of spaces, but I would like for the search function look for both hyphens and spaces in a result.

For example, if they have a post named "SQL-IS AWESOME" and I search for "SQL IS AWESOME", can I still find that post? I tried using 2 sql queries, one for the original search query, and one modified to change all spaces to hyphens.

But if I search "SQL IS-AWESOME" it still won't find it. Is there an easier way?

My current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE (post_title='".$query."' 
OR post_title LIKE '%".$query."' 
OR post_title LIKE '%".$query."%' 
OR post_title LIKE '".$query."%') 
".$locquery."
".$cat."
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 18";
```

Comment: `select 'sql is awesome' = replace('sql-is-awesome', '-', ' ')`

Comment: i would strip hyphens and spaces then use a full text search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @MarcB not sure I understand? is that php? or sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone has suggested, you could just adapt and use fulltext searching.

If you choose to take this route, you will need to enable fulltext searching on the fields required.

I'll assume you will check post_title and post_body (?), which needs you to run this;

```
ALTER TABLE `posts` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `post_search` (`post_title`,`post_body`);
```

When that is done, your search query can easily be edited to become;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE MATCH(post_title,post_body) AGAINST '$search'";
```

If you'd like better matching, it is also possible to give it a score and order by that, which would require code similar to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, MATCH(post_title, post_body) AGAINST ('{$search}') AS score ".
       "FROM `posts` WHERE MATCH(post_title, post_body) AGAINST ('{$search}') ORDER BY `score` DESC";
```

--- NOTES

For the search, you need to work out how you will be searching.

In the last instance I used similar, I simply had a form for the search term (Named "Search") resulting in $_POST['search'] being sent to the server.

I then used;

```
$search = (array_key_exists('search', $_POST) && is_string($_POST['search'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'], $c) : FALSE ;
if ($search) {
    // Do the fulltext query requires (See above)
}
```

---

Since fulltext search will disregard the hyphen, you are left with just spaces, which works great for fulltext, if you opt to use scored results.

Comment: the first one is giving me an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD FULLTEXT KEY `post_search` (`post_title`,`text`)' at line 1

Comment: Amended post. It should have been ALTER TABLE, not UPDATE -- oops.

Comment: actually, the third one works. But it still doesn't help with the fact that I need to search for hyphens instead of spaces...

Comment: You want it to search with or without hyphens, right? Using the above with the score system, for example, would put "random-name-selected" as the top result for the search terms "random name selected" and "random-name-selected" -- is this not the required effect you were aiming for?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't test correctly. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: wait, but if I dont type out the first word completely then it doesnt return anything

Comment: Can you give an example of how you mean that? Does the first word, with missing letters, have 3 or more characters? FullText has a 3 character limit to limit results to relevant result sets.

I am currently throwing together a database to test what you have said -- will post back shortly.

Comment: My client needs it to be instant search. Lets say I have a post called "testing" and I type in "tes" it should still be able to find it.